# $rootScope.$on the ajax call going repeatedly

Tags: angularjs

I want to auto refresh the dashboard after update the data from modal.

1. In modal popup, In update click action.. by using $rootScope.$emit calling the parent controller.
2. in parent controller

   ```
   $scope.updateCard = $rootScope.$on("child_to_parent", function(event) {
        ajaxFunction(function(data) {
            $scope.myData = data.message;
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

        });
    }
   ```

here after update, ajax call is going more than once.

how can I prevent the more calls?

Comment: Can you show us more code? Also, I think you made a mistake with the existing code. Is it supposed to be `$scope.updateCard = function () { ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your update of `$scope.myData` triggers the event `child_to_parent` again. So come the recursive calling.

Answer (score 0):

You can put set a flag that will prevent further ajax calls while one is going on..

```
    $scope.isAjaxCallFinished = true;

    $scope.updateCard = function(event) {
         if ($scope.isAjaxCallFinished) {
             $scope.isAjaxCallFinished = false;
             ajaxFunction(function(data) {
                 $scope.myData = data.message;
                 event.preventDefault();
                 event.stopPropagation();
                $scope.isAjaxCallFinished = false;
             });
         }

     }
```